# Injecting Controller vs Injecting Service inside Razor view

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, dependency-injection

What is the best practice in injecting dependencies inside Razor view?

We can use Controller as a service and inject that or inject Service

I don't know what is the cons and pros of these injecting ways.

1. Controller:

in Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     .
     .
     .
    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddControllersAsServices().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
 }
```

then
inside home.cshtml

```
@inject CourseController _courseControler 
.
.
.
<select asp-for="CategoryID" class="form-control round">
   @foreach (var item in await _courseControler.GetAllCourceCategory()){
      <option value="@item.ID">@item.Description</option>
   } 
</select>
```

2. Service:

in Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     .
     .
     .
    services.AddTransient<ICourseService, CourseService>();
 }
```

then
inside home.cshtml

```
@inject ICourseService _courseService
.
.
.
<select asp-for="CategoryID" class="form-control round">
   @foreach (var item in await _courseService.GetAllCourceCategory()){
      <option value="@item.ID">@item.Description</option>
   } 
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will explain this by assuming that the application is a .NET Core **MVC** app. (Indeed the same principles are also applicable to Razor Page application but there will be some difference when implementing it.).

In short, injecting controller or service in a view is not a good idea.

---

#### Using `@inject`

From the [.NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

> ASP.NET Core supports dependency injection into views. This can be useful for **view-specific services**.

So, **View-specific** is the key.

#### Injecting a Controller into a View

Again, from [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/aspnet-mvc-controllers-overview-cs#understanding-controllers):

> MVC controllers are responsible for responding to requests made against an ASP.NET MVC website.

When you inject a **controller** into a **view** file, your controller is NOT doing what it supposed to do.

#### Injecting a Service into a View

If the service is UI-specific, you can do that. You can find [an example from the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-injection).

If your service is not handling UI-specific stuff (e.g. getting data from your database), it should be injected at **controller** level (or, in the `.cshtml.cs` file when you are using Razor Pages).

### Use a View Model

If `ICourseService` is a data-specific service, you should call `_courseService.GetAllCourseCategory()` in the controller action.

You may need a **view model** like this:

```cs
public class HomeViewModel
{
  public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller action:

```cs
// inject ICourseService in the controller constructor
public Task<IActionResult> Home()
{
  var viewModel = new HomeViewModel
  {
    Courses = await _courseService.GetAllCourseCategory()
  };
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

In the view file:

```html
@model HomeViewModel
<select asp-for="CategoryID" class="form-control round">
  @foreach (var item in Model.Courses) {
    <option value="@item.ID">@item.Description</option>
  } 
</select>
```

Now this is what a typical MVC application looks like.

---

### Conclusion

You *can* inject a controller or a service in the view file but most of the time you *shouldn't* do so in a MVC application. This violates the purpose of the controller and the view. Similarly, injecting a non-UI specific service to the view also violates the purpose of a view.

Use a **model** to carry your data (retrieved from services). Use a **controller** for the flow. Use a **view** to render your model. That's how **MVC** works.